# Working with output from Blink-Diff

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I just using tool name 'blink-diff' from https://www.npmjs.com/package/blink-diff

It's a tool that we use to capture image of the website page before/after to compare. The result of image will have same percentage to decide success or fail like % > xxx 'SUCCESS' or % < xxx 'FAIL'.

Seem everything working fine. But, I have some problem about the output. I need to separate out the file/image that 'FAIL'. I have some idea that.. maybe I should write shell script to read some output. If had text fail will cp to another folder or sth.

Here the some of the output

./compare.sh
samplewebsite1.com
Blink-Diff 1.0.13
Copyright (C) 2014 Yahoo! Inc.
Images are identical or near identical
Wrote differences to report/sameplewebsite1.com
Differences: 0 (0%)
PASS

samplewebsite2.com
Blink-Diff 1.0.13
Copyright (C) 2014 Yahoo! Inc.
Clipping to 800 x 6310
Images are visibly different
1231068 pixels are different
Wrote differences to report/sameplewebsite2.com
Time: 5888.025ms
Differences: 1231068 (24.39%)

FAIL

Please feel free to suggest any idea to solve this problem. I really appreciate it : )

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify the key string for PASS or FAIL string and use grep for those line and redirect to another file . 
Sample ans :
./compare.sh |grep "FAIL STRING" >>$fail_output_file